# MYSQL, error 150

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have error # 150.
I was looking on different forums, but all they said is that there must be same types for foreign key.

And here's my code:

```
USE `dbask`;
set names utf8;

/*users*/
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id`                INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username`          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `password`          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `permission`        VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    `firstname`         VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    `lastname`          VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    `birthdate`         VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `picture_link`      VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


/*questions*/
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
    `id`                INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username`          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `asked_username`    VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    `question`          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `answer`            VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `time_asked`        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_questions_to_users`
        FOREIGN KEY (`username`)
        REFERENCES `users`(`username`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
     )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Both types are `VARCHAR(30)` so I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not referencing the user ID instead of username?

Comment: I keep as cookie encoded username, so I thought it would be less queries for db.

Comment: I think your assumption is wrong. The int indexes are the fastest ones available in mysql. And username is not exactly a "unchangeable" value, it can be changed more often than id can.

Comment: I would strongly suggest keeping track of the user ID instead of the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create **username** as **PRIMARY KEY** in **Users** table then you can create **FOREIGN KEY** on **questions** table. Or you can use **UNIQUE KEY** to create **FOREIGN KEY** as shown below

**Deviation from SQL standards:** A FOREIGN KEY constraint that references a non-UNIQUE key is not standard SQL. It is an InnoDB extension to standard SQL.

```
USE `dbask`;
SET NAMES utf8;

/*users*/
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id`                INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username`          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `password`          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `permission`        VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    `firstname`         VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    `lastname`          VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    `birthdate`         VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `picture_link`      VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY (username))
ENGINE = INNODB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


/*questions*/
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
    `id`                INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username`          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `asked_username`    VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    `question`          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `answer`            VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `time_asked`        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_questions_to_users`
        FOREIGN KEY (`username`)
        REFERENCES `users`(`username`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
     )
ENGINE = INNODB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: So I cannot reference not primary key??

Comment: You can't reference any non primary key column

Comment: You have to crate Unique key on username column in user table

Answer (score 0):

[My SQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

> Deviation from SQL standards: A FOREIGN KEY constraint that references
>   a non-UNIQUE key is not standard SQL. It is an InnoDB extension to
>   standard SQL.